# Sitecore 9.2 Dependency Injection in ApiController

Tags: dependency-injection, webapi

I have a standard `.net ApiController` with the following code:

```
public class LibraryApiController : ApiController
{
    private readonly ILibraryAssetRepository _repository;

    public LibraryApiController() : this(new LibraryAssetRepository())
    {

    }

    public LibraryApiController(ILibraryAssetRepository repository)
    {
        if(repository == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(repository));

        _repository = repository;
    }
}
```

I would like to get rid of the parameterless constructor, but then I run into the dreaded:

> An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type
>   'ApiController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless
>   public constructor.

I am using Sitecore's builtin dependency injection `(Microsoft.DependencyInjection)`

I have only found examples using SitecoreApiControllers. How do I solve this using an ApiController?

Comment: Can you the Sitecore ServicesController ? it inherits from ApiController

Comment: https://letsdositecore.wordpress.com/2018/11/13/possibly-simplest-way-of-enabling-dependency-injection-in-sitecore-controllers-and-apicontrollers/ there is an example for ApiControllers as well

Comment: @AbhayDhar If you add a commen/answer about the part where an ApiController is registered and write an example:

serviceCollection.AddTransient(typeof(GenericCalloutApiController));

I will mark that answer as accepted solution.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described in this blog post -https://letsdositecore.wordpress.com/2018/11/13/possibly-simplest-way-of-enabling-dependency-injection-in-sitecore-controllers-and-apicontrollers/ , you can use a ServiceConfigurator to register your API controllers using Sitecore DI. Don't forget to patch it in.

```
namespace Feature.GenericCallout
{
    public class GenericCalloutServicesConfigurator : IServicesConfigurator
    {
        public void Configure(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
        {
            serviceCollection.AddTransient(typeof(GenericCalloutController));
            serviceCollection.AddTransient(typeof(GenericCalloutApiController));
        }
    }
}
```